# Puppet file source (recurse => true) + hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a bunch of files that need be copied to the node.

I'm doing this using File resource.

```
file { '/etc/myapp/conf':
    path         => '/etc/myapp/conf',
    ensure       => directory,
    source       => 'puppet:///myapp/conf_files',
    recurse      => true,
}
```

Inside the **myapp/conf_files** folder I have a lot of files, such as: **myapp.xml** and **myapp.properties**.

Is it possible to use hiera to parameterise those files copied by the File resource ? I mean, for every file copied **tokens** defined in the files be replaced by a Hiera lookup value.

I think that I can't use the template() because the number and names of the file might vary for each node/environment, and I cannot have these templates hard-coded in the .pp. This should be something dynamic.

And I also need to use the Hiera hierarchies approach to correctly pick the values up.

Comment: No, I don't believe this is possible with the `source` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard, any suggestion in how could I achieve this ?

Comment: Basically use the `template()` function with the `content` attribute.